# Android relative layout using dp jumps all over

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I've tried to match as exactly as possible the tablet this is being designed for, a Samsung Tab S2 - 9.7" screen size, 2048x1536 - I've created an AVD to match that.

I've lined up the images as shown here:

[image]

But when I deploy it, they jump around, as shown here:

[image]

They get even worse depending on other tablets, but I'm just trying one for now. I'm using a full screen relative layout with DP for the dimensions and margins, so why do they jump around so much? Shouldn't it always be the same distance from the top/sides? How come even though the dimensions and pixels match exactly in the AVD and the tablet, it moves around?

I'm completely lost, I've read everything I can from setting margins in code to absolute layouts (no longer supported). Everything points back to DP, but even using an exact match tablet and designer, they change location and size.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_buttons"
tools:context="com.cimulus.samocoseat.MainMenu">

<!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
     android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/seatView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/seat"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:text="Seat Back Forward"
            android:id="@+id/seatBackForward"
            android:background="@drawable/left_inactive"
            android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="38dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:text="Seat Back Forward"
            android:id="@+id/legRightExtension"
            android:background="@drawable/left_inactive"
            android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I've also tried the relative layout existing on it's own, which gives me the same results overall:

```
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/background_buttons">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/seatView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/seat"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="245dp"
            />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:text="Seat Back Forward"
            android:id="@+id/seatBackForward"
            android:background="@drawable/left_inactive"
            android:layout_marginTop="266dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="38dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="124dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:text="Seat Back Forward"
            android:id="@+id/legRightExtension"
            android:background="@drawable/left_inactive"
            android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Mate, using Relative Layout and hardcoded values for widths, heights, margins etc will **never** work across devices. Rather use LinearLayouts, PercentRelativeLayouts or GridLayouts.

Comment: for the arrows, instead of using absolute margins from screen edges, use center text as anchor. use attributes like layout_above, layout_below, layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf

Comment: Part of what's confusing me is the fact that laying it out with the correct dimensions and DPI for targeting a specific tablet doesn't match the design vs the product. I'm trying to get this rough layout, with images where the buttons are: https://i.imgur.com/CLNju6y.png Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and someone suggested using this library - https://github.com/intuit/sdp . It provides units, that are automatically scaled across devices with different screen characteristics. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it - I'm looking to create a layout like this: https://i.imgur.com/CLNju6y.png Do you have an idea on the best way to create such a staggered layout?